# Is there a python way of doing this: gcloud datastore operations describe <job>?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using `gcloud datastore operations describe <job>` to check the status of my google cloud export. Is there a way to do this with python?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. From [Exporting and Importing Entities](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities):

> This page describes how to export and import Google Cloud Datastore
>   entities using the managed export and import service. The managed
>   export and import service is available through the `gcloud`
>   command-line tool and the Cloud Datastore Admin API ([REST](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/),
>   [RPC](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rpc/)).

You're probably looking for either of:

- REST: [Method: projects.operations.get](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/v1/projects.operations/get)

> Gets the latest state of a long-running operation. Clients can use
>   this method to poll the operation result at intervals as recommended
>   by the API service.
>
> HTTP request
>
> ```
> GET https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/{name=projects/*/operations/*}
> ```

- RPC: [GetOperation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rpc/google.longrunning#google.longrunning.Operations.GetOperation)

> rpc GetOperation([GetOperationRequest](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rpc/google.longrunning#google.longrunning.GetOperationRequest)) returns ([Operation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rpc/google.longrunning#google.longrunning.Operation))
>
> Gets the latest state of a long-running operation. Clients can use
>   this method to poll the operation result at intervals as recommended
>   by the API service.